# Is it safe to have password in Espresso tests? (Android)

Tags: android, android-espresso

There is an Android app with Espresso tests.

The whole app requires me to login to Firebase first, so the Espresso tests log in with a valid email/password.

I guess the code for the Espresso tests (`/project/app/scr/androidTest/`) is not included in the release package (`app-release.apk`), so it should be fairly safe to leave the actual email/password in the code for the test.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct. Code from flavors are not bundled on different builds than its own.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is a bad practice to commit code that contains sensitive information such as passwords. Instead, **your credentials should be set as environment variables or a `.gitignore`'d config file that gets injected to your tests**. Never hardcoded your passwords in your code.

Other than that, you should have a Firebase instance that is specifically for tests. You should not run your tests against the production instance.